# How can I remove double quotes from a string

Tags: c#

I have a variable "currntdate" of type string

The value of the variable is `"'2017-08-03'"` (quotes included)

Now i want to remove the double quotes `"`.

How can I do that in C#?

Comment: `currntdate = currntdate.Replace("\"", "")` will leave you with `'2017-08-03'` but your question is unclear.

Comment: currntdate = currntdate.Replace("\", "");

Comment: I rephrased the question as the original wording was very difficult to figure out. The OP's request, while particularly trivial and lacking research, seems legitimate to me

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ it's very tempting to correct the spelling of the variable name too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposed you have

```
var currntDate =  @"""'2017-08-03'""";
```

Just use

```
currntDate = currntDate.Replace("\"","");
```

Comment: Double quotes are the only character to be escaped when using a verbatim `@`